# Unit test for CreateFolder() method

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I am trying to write a unit test for the following method, but I do not know how to do it. Would you please help me with what could be the best approach to do it?

```cs
public void CreateFolder()
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Temp/")))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Temp/"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it can be applied here, but for tricky stuff often mocking is used https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/fundamental-of-unit-testing-understand-mock-object-in-unit/ https://scottlilly.com/creating-mock-objects-for-c-unit-tests-using-moq/

Comment: You need to create a mockable interface that wraps those static methods.